# how can I write loop function in R to repeat these codes for each row

Tags: r, loops

#gg is my data frame as it contain 1000 different seqname

```
seqname       start  end
 scaffold02439   843 1180
 scaffold02439   928 1180
 scaffold02439  3560 3672
 scaffold02439  3560 3672
 scaffold02439  5525 5666
 scaffold02439  5525 5666
```

#I want to take the start and end value of each seqname

```
c <- unique(gg$seqname)
l1 <- gg %>% filter(seqname %in% c[1] )
l1a <- l1[1,2]
l1b <- l1[nrow(l1),3]
l1 <- cbind(c[1],l1a,l1b)
l2 <- gg %>% filter(seqname %in% c[2])
l2a <- l2[1,2]
l2b <- l2[nrow(l2),3]
l2 <- cbind(c[2],l2a,l2b)
```

How can I write this in loop form to extract each value and then take the start (2nd column) of the first row and end (third column) of last row of this data

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this

```
library(dplyr)

gg %>% group_by(seqname) %>%                       #group by seqname
   summarise(start = first(start), end = last(end))#extract first and last
```

This will return the first and last entries, which are not necessarily the minimum and maximum values of `start` and `end`. If you want this instead, just use `summarise(start = min(start), end = max(end))`.

Comment: thanks for your reply; however,I got this error Error: Problem with `summarise()` input `start`.
x unable to find an inherited method for function ‘first’ for signature ‘"integer"’
ℹ Input `start` is `first(ref)`.
ℹ The error occurred in group 1: seqname = "scaffold00001".
Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.

Comment: What do you get if you run `str(gg)`?

Comment: 'data.frame': 1048576 obs. of  3 variables:
 $ seqname: chr  "scaffold02439" "scaffold02439" "scaffold02439" "scaffold02439" ...
 $ start  : int  843 928 3560 3560 5525 5525 5743 5743 3297 3297 ...
 $ end    : int  1180 1180 3672 3672 5666 5666 5909 5909 3506 3506 ...

Comment: I'm not sure why you would get the error, although I think I misunderstood what you were asking, so have updated the answer above.

Answer (score 0):

We can also use `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(gg)[, .(start = first(start), end = last(end)), seqname]
```